# chroot error : "I: arm64 cannot be executed, falling back to qemu-user"

Tags: debian, qemu, chroot, arm, error-handling

I set up a `arm64` chroot named via this command:

```
sudo mmdebstrap --architectures=arm64 buster myArm64Machine
```

entered said chroot with command below:

```
sudo chroot gnome-core-arm64 myArm64Machine
```

one of output lines was this error:

```
> I: arm64 cannot be executed, falling back to qemu-user
```

Why this error occured and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “I:” at the start of the line indicates that it’s not an error, it’s an informative message. The system is informing you that, because `arm64` binaries can’t be executed natively, it’s using QEMU.